# Deploy VSTS Web Deploy package from Agent machine to another machine

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webdeploy, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to implement CI/CD for a web application hosted in a local network. Which means the local machine/IIS server which hosted the web application is not directly connected to the internet (so not a VSTS agent).

So we are putting a virtual machine acts as an intermediary between internet & local intranet machines. The Azure DevOps release pipeline will copy the deployment package to this "Virtual Machine"

Now I want to deploy this package to another machine in the local network which is actually hosting the application for an intranet. How can we achieve this step in the release pipeline?

[image]

Comment: You should be able to access powershell on the Agent and do a file copy from there, provided they're networked appropriately

Answer (score 0):

I have tried below solution and it seems ok for me.

1. From Azure Release Pipeline, copy the build artifacts to a local path in the server (mentioned as "Virtual machine" in question)
2. Using MSDeploy.exe to deploy the release artifact to an intranet website hosted on "Local Machine" IIS.
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/web-deployment-in-the-enterprise/deploying-web-packages

Note: The destination local machine should be configured for WebDeploy as instructed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-server-environments-for-web-deployment/configuring-a-web-server-for-web-deploy-publishing-web-deploy-handler

[image]